# Firefox SVG image is cut off when I use external stylesheet

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

Given the SVG file at http://dpaste.com/756156/ when I display it in a `<object>` or `<embed>` tag, about half the time it loads in Firefox the bottom portion of the image is cut off. Using inline CSS renders it fine, and Chrome and IE9 render properly as well.

I've seen suggestions to add width and height attributes of "100%" to the SVG tag, but that hasn't helped. Any ideas?

Comment: Change the classname of the `<object>` or `<embed>` tag in the window.onload event?

Comment: Currently my `window.onload` triggers the rendering of the SVG. I have some code to detect support for SVG and if present, replace a PNG with my SVG

Answer (score 3):

Having just suffered this issue myself [svg being clipped in firefox] I found a solution.
It's a bit random and has no logic, but it fixed the issue for me.

My svg was a simple "cloud" shape drawn with Illustrator using bezier curves.
No matter how many times I drew it, the right-hand side (kind of a bubble shape) was being clipped by the browser. No amount of adjusting parameters (such as viewBox, x, y, width, height) would fix it. - It was still clipped. In fact by adjusting these parameters it became obvious that it wasn't caused by any of them.

The solution was to add more data to the curve.  I simply added another anchor-point on the curve that was being clipped, and hey presto it rendered properly in firefox.

Random but true. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by Firefox rendering the SVG before loading the stylesheet, then not realizing that it needs to update it.  Try changing the classname of the SVG tag in the `onload` event (JavaScript), as suggested by this page: http://ajaxian.com/archives/forcing-a-ui-redraw-from-javascript

If that doesn't work?  Try completely regenerating the element with `elm.parentNode.innerHTML += ''` as suggested in the comments to this StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922034/638544

Comment: Assuming I implemented that regeneration right, it just duplicates the element so I see two copies of the SVG

Comment: Actually, sometimes it gives me two, sometimes it renders it properly.

Comment: Hmm, I was assuming that the stylesheet you were talking about was loaded in the HTML head.  Apparently the stylesheet is loaded by the SVG file - the only workaround I can think of is to give the SVG tag the actual width and height (in pixels/EMs) that you want it to display at.  Or... possibly examine the SVG with JavaScript, extract that information and apply it to the `<object>`? (Actually, giving it the exact width and height of the previous `<img>` element is probably your best bet.)

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me, after dealing with multiple chart libraries.

First, set the chart's SVG to visibility: hidden; in the CSS eg.(#pie_chart .ct-chart-pie {visibility: hidden;} )

Then re-render the chart and change visibility to visible.

```
function show_popup(){ 
   Chartist.Pie('#pie_chart', data, options, responsiveOptions); 
   $("#pie_chart .ct-chart-pie").attr("style","visibility:visible !important;");   
}; 
window.setTimeout( show_popup, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed recently by bug [1063073](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1063073). The fix will appear in Firefox 34, after that workarounds will no longer be necessary.